# How can I add List in poi word, ordered number or other symbol for list symbol?

Tags: apache-poi

everyone! 
first, I want to add list in my poi word(XWPF),
second, I want to using black cube as the list symbol like picture as below. 
third, what I should to do if ordered number instead of the black cube symbol. Could someone give me some advice? Thanks so lot!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since for new adding a new AbstractNum in [XWPFNumbering](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFNumbering.html), [XWPFAbstractNum](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFAbstractNum.html) is needed and this is not able to create without using underlaying low level objects until now, at least `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum` is needed.

There are methods in [CTAbstractNum](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTAbstractNum.java) for creating the single sub objects therein. But the resulting code would be very small part code and so much many code lines would be necessary. So the best way in my opinion is parsing `XML` for creating the  AbstractNum. To get this `XML` one can create a simple `Word`document having numbering and then unzip the `*.docx` file and have a look at `/word/numbering.xml`. There you will find something like:

```
<w:numbering>
 <w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="0">
  <w:multiLevelType w:val="hybridMultilevel"/>
  <w:lvl w:ilvl="0">
   <w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/><w:lvlText w:val="%1"/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
   <w:pPr>
    <w:ind w:hanging="360" w:left="720"/>
   </w:pPr>
  </w:lvl>
  <w:lvl w:ilvl="1" w:tentative="1">
   <w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/><w:lvlText w:val="%1.%2"/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
   <w:pPr>
    <w:ind w:hanging="360" w:left="1440"/>
   </w:pPr>
  </w:lvl>
  <w:lvl w:ilvl="2" w:tentative="1">
   <w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/><w:lvlText w:val="%1.%2.%3"/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
   <w:pPr>
    <w:ind w:hanging="360" w:left="2160"/>
   </w:pPr>
  </w:lvl>
 </w:abstractNum>
...
</w:numbering>
```

for a 3 level decimal numbering for example.

This `XML` is self explained in my opinion. There is a `lvl` definition for each numbering level having definitions for it's appearance and indention.

For a bullet numbering the `XML`will be similar but the glyphs for the bullet characters used will be additional defined using `Font` definition. The "black cube" for example is a glyph from font `Wingdings`.

```
...
<w:lvl w:ilvl="0">
 <w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="bullet"/><w:lvlText w:val=" "/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
 <w:pPr>
  <w:ind w:hanging="360" w:left="720"/>
 </w:pPr>
 <w:rPr>
  <w:rFonts w:ascii="Wingdings" w:hAnsi="Wingdings" w:hint="default"/>
 </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
...
```

The space in `w:val=" "` is the default font glyph representation for the unicode code point `F06E`. This is used because the ASCII code point `6E` is showing the glyph "black cube" in Wingdings but the glyph `n` in normal fonts. That couls lead to irritations if the font Wingdings is not available. Thats why unicode `F06E` is used instaed of ASCII `6E`.

Knowing this we can code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTNumbering;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordBulletOrDecimalList {

 static String cTAbstractNumBulletXML = 
  "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"0\">"
+ "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\uF06E\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Wingdings\" w:hAnsi=\"Wingdings\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\u2013\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:cs=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\u26Ac\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2160\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "</w:abstractNum>";

 static String cTAbstractNumDecimalXML = 
  "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"0\">"
+ "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2.%3\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2160\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "</w:abstractNum>";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The List:");

  CTNumbering cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(cTAbstractNumBulletXML);
  //CTNumbering cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(cTAbstractNumDecimalXML);

  CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = cTNumbering.getAbstractNumArray(0);

  XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);

  XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();

  BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);

  BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setNumID(numID);
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText("List item " + (i+1)); 
   if (i < 4) paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
   if (i == 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
     paragraph = document.createParagraph();
     paragraph.setNumID(numID);
     paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().addNewIlvl().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
     run = paragraph.createRun();
     run.setText("Sub list item " + (i+1) + " " + (char)(97+j));
     paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
    }
   }
   if (i == 1 || i == 3) {
    paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    paragraph.setNumID(numID);
    paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().addNewIlvl().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Sub list item " + (i+1) + " a");
    paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0); 
   }
  }

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Paragraph after the list.");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordBulletOrDecimalList.docx");    
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

  System.out.println("CreateWordBulletOrDecimalList written successully");
 }
}
```

---

Code for using both kind of lists in one document:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTNumbering;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordBulletAndDecimalList {

 static String cTAbstractNumBulletXML = 
  "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"0\">"
+ "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\uF06E\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Wingdings\" w:hAnsi=\"Wingdings\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\u2013\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:cs=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\u26Ac\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2160\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "</w:abstractNum>";

 static String cTAbstractNumDecimalXML = 
  "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"1\">"
+ "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2.%3\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2160\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "</w:abstractNum>";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  CTNumbering cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(cTAbstractNumBulletXML);
  CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = cTNumbering.getAbstractNumArray(0);
  XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum1 = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);


  cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(cTAbstractNumDecimalXML);
  cTAbstractNum = cTNumbering.getAbstractNumArray(0);
  XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum2 = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);

  XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();

  BigInteger abstractNumID1 = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum1);
  BigInteger numID1 = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID1);

  BigInteger abstractNumID2 = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum2);
  BigInteger numID2 = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID2);

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The lists:");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The bullet list:");

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setNumID(numID1);
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText("List item " + (i+1)); 
   if (i < 4) paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
   if (i == 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
     paragraph = document.createParagraph();
     paragraph.setNumID(numID1);
     paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().addNewIlvl().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
     run = paragraph.createRun();
     run.setText("Sub list item " + (i+1) + " " + (char)(97+j));
     paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
    }
   }
   if (i == 1 || i == 3) {
    paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    paragraph.setNumID(numID1);
    paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().addNewIlvl().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Sub list item " + (i+1) + " a");
    paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0); 
   }
  }

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The decimal list:");

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setNumID(numID2);
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText("List item " + (i+1)); 
   if (i < 4) paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
   if (i == 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
     paragraph = document.createParagraph();
     paragraph.setNumID(numID2);
     paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().addNewIlvl().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
     run = paragraph.createRun();
     run.setText("Sub list item " + (i+1) + " " + (char)(97+j));
     paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
    }
   }
   if (i == 1 || i == 3) {
    paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    paragraph.setNumID(numID2);
    paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().addNewIlvl().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Sub list item " + (i+1) + " a");
    paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0); 
   }
  }

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Paragraph after the lists.");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordBulletAndDecimalList.docx");    
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

  System.out.println("CreateWordBulletAndDecimalList written successully");
 }
}
```

Comment: If  I used cTAbstractNumBulletXML and cTAbstractNumDecimalXML both , I found that the latter will instead of the before. There are two method getList1(),getList2() , is used cTAbstractNumBulletXML  and cTAbstractNumDecimalXML respectively, but getList1() will change into getList2()'s style, what wrong with it?

Comment: My sample code is either or, for **either** using `cTAbstractNumBulletXML` **or** using `cTAbstractNumDecimalXML`. If you need both, you will need two different `XWPFAbstractNum` `abstractNum1` and `abstractNum2` both added to the `XWPFNumbering numbering` resulting in two different `BigInteger` `abstractNumID1`and `abstractNumID2` and also two different `BigInteger` `numID1`and `numID2`. The different numIDs used in `paragraph.setNumID` will then set the different kinds of numbering for the paragraph.

Comment: Forgot one thing: `w:abstractNumId="0"` must not be both `0` in `XML`. One of it must be different. I have now provided sample code using both kind of lists.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your answer is very valuable.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about [my questions..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335464/how-to-set-table-of-contents-font-style-including-font-color-font-size-and-bol/43344821#43344821)? Maybe I should reproduce style.xml, but I don't know the relationship connects document.xml and styles.xml, and how to set styles ids inside document.xml to connect concrete text part with concrete style. I should expend huge effort to do this. Do your have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I didn't express my question clearly. My question is [this is a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335464/how-to-set-table-of-contents-font-style-including-font-color-font-size-and-bol/43344821#43344821), this questions have nothing with the list symbol above, I want to create a table of content and want to change TOC's style, I think you maybe can provide me some advice of my question. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335464/how-to-set-table-of-contents-font-style-including-font-color-font-size-and-bol/43447843#43447843