# How to change the color, font of TOC in word using ApachePOI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.16. Please help to change the color and font style of TOC contents.

Thank you!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335464/how-to-set-table-of-contents-font-style-including-font-color-font-size-and-bol/43447843#43447843?