# how to set font for toc in word by poi

Tags: java, fonts, apache-poi, tableofcontents

I have created the TOC, and I want to set the TOC font, paragraph spacing and indentation style. Following is my code.
The style of the screenshot is my want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI3QH.png)
Please help me, and thanks!

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordNumberedHeadings {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    static String cTStyleTOC1 ="<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:type=\"paragraph\" w:styleId=\"TOC1\">"
                + "<w:name w:val=\"toc 1\"/>"
                + "<w:basedOn w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
                + "<w:next w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
                + "<w:autoRedefine/><w:unhideWhenUsed/>"
                + "<w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"仿宋_GB2312\" w:cs=\"仿宋_GB2312\" /><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:caps/><w:sz w:val=\"20\"/><w:szCs w:val=\"20\"/></w:rPr>"
                + "</w:style>";

    static String cTStyleTOC2 ="<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:type=\"paragraph\" w:styleId=\"TOC2\">"
                + "<w:name w:val=\"toc 2\"/>"
                + "<w:basedOn w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
                + "<w:next w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
                + "<w:autoRedefine/><w:unhideWhenUsed/>"
                + "<w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"仿宋_GB2312\" w:cs=\"仿宋_GB2312\" /><w:sz w:val=\"20\"/><w:szCs w:val=\"20\"/></w:rPr>"
                + "</w:style>";

    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    createTOC(document);
    createtFirstTitle(document, "First Title");
    createtSecondTitle(document, "Second Title");
    createtSecondTitle(document, "Second Title");
    createtContent(document, "content ....");
    createtFirstTitle(document, "First Title");
    createtSecondTitle(document, "Second Title");
    createtSecondTitle(document, "Second Title");
    createtContent(document, "content ....");

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("f:\\CreateWordNumberedHeadings.docx");
    document.write(out);
  }
  private static void createTOC( XWPFDocument document) throws XmlException {
    XWPFParagraph p = document.createParagraph();
    p.setSpacingBetween(1.25);
    p.setSpacingBeforeLines(150);
    p.setSpacingAfterLines(150);
    p.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    XWPFRun r = p.createRun();
    r.setText("目  录");
    r.setFontFamily("黑体");
    r.setFontSize(15);
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    CTSimpleField toc = paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
    toc.setInstr("TOC \\* MERGEFORMAT");
    toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);
    XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();
    addCustomHeadingStyle(styles,"index1",0);
    addCustomHeadingStyle(styles,"index2",1);
    CTStyles cTStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(cTStyleTOC1);
    CTStyle cTStyle = cTStyles.getStyleArray(0);
    styles.addStyle(new XWPFStyle(cTStyle));
    cTStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(cTStyleTOC2);
    cTStyle = cTStyles.getStyleArray(0);
    styles.addStyle(new XWPFStyle(cTStyle));
  }
  private static void addCustomHeadingStyle(XWPFStyles styles, String strStyleId, int headingLevel) {
    CTStyle ctStyle = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setStyleId(strStyleId);
    CTString styleName = CTString.Factory.newInstance();
    styleName.setVal(strStyleId);
    ctStyle.setName(styleName);
    CTDecimalNumber indentNumber = CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();
    indentNumber.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(headingLevel));
    // lower number > style is more prominent in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setUiPriority(indentNumber);
    CTOnOff onoffnull = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setUnhideWhenUsed(onoffnull);
    // style shows up in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setQFormat(onoffnull);
    // style defines a heading of the given level
    CTPPr ppr = CTPPr.Factory.newInstance();
    ppr.setOutlineLvl(indentNumber);
    ctStyle.setPPr(ppr);
    XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(ctStyle);
    style.setType(STStyleType.PARAGRAPH);
    styles.addStyle(style);
  }
  public static void createtFirstTitle(XWPFDocument doc,String title){
    XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
    para.setSpacingBetween(1.25);
    para.setSpacingBeforeLines(150);
    para.setSpacingAfterLines(150);
    para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    para.setStyle("index1");
    para.setPageBreak(true);
    XWPFRun r = para.createRun();
    r.setText(title);
    r.setFontSize(15);
    r.setFontFamily("黑体");

  }
  public static void createtSecondTitle(XWPFDocument doc,String title){
    XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
    para.setStyle("index2");
    para.setFirstLineIndent(600);
    para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    para.setSpacingBetween(1.25);
    para.setSpacingBefore(270);
    para.setSpacingAfter(270);
    XWPFRun r = para.createRun();
    r.setText(title);
    r.setFontSize(14);
    r.setBold(true);
    r.setFontFamily("仿宋_GB2312");
  }
  public static void createtContent(XWPFDocument doc, String content){
    XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
    para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    para.setFirstLineIndent(600);
    para.setSpacingBetween(1.25);
    XWPFRun run = para.createRun();
    run.setText(content);
    run.setFontFamily("仿宋_GB2312");
    run.setFontSize(14);
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335464/how-to-set-table-of-contents-font-style-including-font-color-font-size-and-bol/43447843#43447843

Comment: For font setting a `w:rFonts` is needed in `w:rPr`. Documented in [Office Open 
XML Part 4: Markup Language Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.pdf) -> `2.3.2.24 rFonts (Run Fonts)`. But you should ask more specific. Provide a complete code sample (as in my linked answer) and tell us what shall be different in the result.

Comment: I've told you already what to do: Provide a complete code sample (as in my linked answer) and tell us what result you get and what shall be different in the result. This is nothing what can be solved in a comments discussion. I don't know why your `SimSun` font "doesn't work" what ever "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: Hello Axel Richter, I have provided a complete code sample.Can you give me some advice？ Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating styles `index1` and `index2` for your titles but then you are nevertheless formatting the text runs in the titles manually. But then the manually set formats will not be overridden by the styles in the TOC. Instead the manually set formats will be considered in the TOC also. That makes it possible for a `Word` user to format single headings individually independent of the heading styles. And that individual formatting will be considered in the TOC also. This is one of the main principles of `Microsoft Word`: Global formatting via styles is possible. But individual formatting the single text runs by the user will be considered as the wanted format.

So you should formatting the titles (headings) using the styles only and not manually.

Complete Example using your code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordNumberedHeadings_Bill {

  static String cTStyleTOC1 ="<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:type=\"paragraph\" w:styleId=\"TOC1\">"
                + "<w:name w:val=\"toc 1\"/>"
                + "<w:basedOn w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
                + "<w:next w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
                + "<w:autoRedefine/><w:unhideWhenUsed/>"
                + "<w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"仿宋_GB2312\" w:cs=\"仿宋_GB2312\" /><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:caps/><w:sz w:val=\"20\"/><w:szCs w:val=\"20\"/></w:rPr>"
                + "</w:style>";

  static String cTStyleTOC2 ="<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:type=\"paragraph\" w:styleId=\"TOC2\">"
                + "<w:name w:val=\"toc 2\"/>"
                + "<w:basedOn w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
                + "<w:next w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
                + "<w:autoRedefine/><w:unhideWhenUsed/>"
                + "<w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"仿宋_GB2312\" w:cs=\"仿宋_GB2312\" /><w:sz w:val=\"20\"/><w:szCs w:val=\"20\"/></w:rPr>"
                + "</w:style>";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    createTOC(document);
    createtFirstTitle(document, "First Title");
    createtSecondTitle(document, "Second Title");
    createtSecondTitle(document, "Second Title");
    createtContent(document, "content ....");
    createtFirstTitle(document, "First Title");
    createtSecondTitle(document, "Second Title");
    createtSecondTitle(document, "Second Title");
    createtContent(document, "content ....");

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordNumberedHeadings_Bill.docx");
    document.write(out);
  }

  private static void createTOC( XWPFDocument document) throws XmlException {
    XWPFParagraph p = document.createParagraph();
    p.setSpacingBetween(1.25);
    p.setSpacingBeforeLines(150);
    p.setSpacingAfterLines(150);
    p.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    XWPFRun r = p.createRun();
    r.setText("目  录");
    r.setFontFamily("黑体");
    r.setFontSize(15);
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    CTSimpleField toc = paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
    toc.setInstr("TOC \\* MERGEFORMAT");
    toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);
    XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();
    addCustomHeadingStyle(styles,"index1", 0, "黑体", 15f, false);
    addCustomHeadingStyle(styles,"index2", 1, "仿宋_GB2312", 14f, true);
    CTStyles cTStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(cTStyleTOC1);
    CTStyle cTStyle = cTStyles.getStyleArray(0);
    styles.addStyle(new XWPFStyle(cTStyle));
    cTStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(cTStyleTOC2);
    cTStyle = cTStyles.getStyleArray(0);
    styles.addStyle(new XWPFStyle(cTStyle));
  }

  private static void addCustomHeadingStyle(XWPFStyles styles, String strStyleId, int headingLevel, String fontFamily, float fontSize, boolean bold) {
    CTStyle ctStyle = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setStyleId(strStyleId);
    CTString styleName = CTString.Factory.newInstance();
    styleName.setVal(strStyleId);
    ctStyle.setName(styleName);
    CTDecimalNumber indentNumber = CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();
    indentNumber.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(headingLevel));
    // lower number > style is more prominent in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setUiPriority(indentNumber);
    CTOnOff onoffnull = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setUnhideWhenUsed(onoffnull);
    // style shows up in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setQFormat(onoffnull);
    // style defines a heading of the given level
    CTPPr ppr = CTPPr.Factory.newInstance();
    ppr.setOutlineLvl(indentNumber);
    ctStyle.setPPr(ppr);

    CTRPr rPr = ctStyle.addNewRPr();
    rPr.addNewRFonts().setAscii(fontFamily);
    rPr.getRFonts().setCs(fontFamily);
    rPr.addNewSz().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((long)(fontSize*2)));
    rPr.addNewSzCs().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((long)(fontSize*2)));
    if (bold) {
     rPr.addNewB();
     rPr.addNewBCs();
    }

    XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(ctStyle);
    style.setType(STStyleType.PARAGRAPH);
    styles.addStyle(style);
  }

  public static void createtFirstTitle(XWPFDocument doc,String title){
    XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
    para.setSpacingBetween(1.25);
    para.setSpacingBeforeLines(150);
    para.setSpacingAfterLines(150);
    para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    para.setStyle("index1");
    para.setPageBreak(true);
    XWPFRun r = para.createRun();
    r.setText(title);
    //r.setFontSize(15);
    //r.setFontFamily("黑体");
  }

  public static void createtSecondTitle(XWPFDocument doc,String title){
    XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
    para.setStyle("index2");
    para.setFirstLineIndent(600);
    para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    para.setSpacingBetween(1.25);
    para.setSpacingBefore(270);
    para.setSpacingAfter(270);
    XWPFRun r = para.createRun();
    r.setText(title);
    //r.setFontSize(14);
    //r.setBold(true);
    //r.setFontFamily("仿宋_GB2312");
  }

  public static void createtContent(XWPFDocument doc, String content){
    XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
    para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    para.setFirstLineIndent(600);
    para.setSpacingBetween(1.25);
    XWPFRun run = para.createRun();
    run.setText(content);
    run.setFontFamily("仿宋_GB2312");
    run.setFontSize(14);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the TOC is included in a paragraph. You can apply a style to the paragraph by adding properties to the paragraph like

```
CTPPr ctPPr = ctP.isSetPPr() ? ctP.getPPr() : ctP.addNewPPr();
CTString pStyle = ctPPr.isSetPStyle() ? ctPPr.getPStyle() : ctPPr.addNewPStyle();
pStyle.setVal("TOC");
```

Because you are using a simple field, the entire table of contents will use the same style. You will of course need to create a style with the appropriate font.