# Error: union value 'true' does not match any members of 'ST_OnOff in namespace http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/sharedTypes'

Tags: java, apache-poi, tableofcontents

I am trying to create table of content using below code, but table of content are not creating as well as I am getting below error.Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: union value 'true' does not match any members of 'ST_OnOff in namespace [http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/sharedTypes'](http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/sharedTypes%27)

```
 package com.example.demo;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTNumbering;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTStyles;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTStyle;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSimpleField;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordNumberedHeadings {

 static String cTAbstractNumDecimalXML = 
  "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"0\">"
+ "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"360\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2.%3\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "</w:abstractNum>";

 static String cTStyleNormal =
  "<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:type=\"paragraph\" w:default=\"1\" w:styleId=\"Normal\">" 
+ "<w:name w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:qFormat/>"
+ "</w:style>";
 static String cTStyleH1XML =
  "<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:type=\"paragraph\" w:styleId=\"Heading1\">"
+ "<w:name w:val=\"heading 1\"/>"
+ "<w:basedOn w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:next w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:unhideWhenUsed/>"
+ "<w:qFormat/>"
+ "<w:rPr><w:b/><w:sz w:val=\"36\"/></w:rPr>"
+ "</w:style>";
 static String cTStyleH2XML =
  "<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:type=\"paragraph\" w:styleId=\"Heading2\">"
+ "<w:name w:val=\"heading 2\"/>"
+ "<w:basedOn w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:next w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:unhideWhenUsed/>"
+ "<w:qFormat/>"
+ "<w:rPr><w:sz w:val=\"32\"/></w:rPr>"
+ "</w:style>";
 static String cTStyleH3XML =
  "<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:type=\"paragraph\" w:styleId=\"Heading3\">"
+ "<w:name w:val=\"heading 3\"/>"
+ "<w:basedOn w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:next w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:unhideWhenUsed/>"
+ "<w:qFormat/>"
+ "<w:rPr><w:i/><w:sz w:val=\"28\"/></w:rPr>"
+ "</w:style>";

static String cTStyleTOC1 =
  "<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:type=\"paragraph\" w:styleId=\"TOC1\">"
+ "<w:name w:val=\"toc 1\"/>"
+ "<w:basedOn w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:next w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:autoRedefine/><w:unhideWhenUsed/>"
+ "<w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:caps/><w:color w:val=\"C00000\"/><w:sz w:val=\"32\"/><w:szCs w:val=\"32\"/></w:rPr>"
+ "</w:style>";

static String cTStyleTOC2 =
  "<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:type=\"paragraph\" w:styleId=\"TOC2\">"
+ "<w:name w:val=\"toc 2\"/>"
+ "<w:basedOn w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:next w:val=\"Normal\"/>"
+ "<w:autoRedefine/><w:unhideWhenUsed/>"
+ "<w:rPr><w:i/><w:iCs/><w:sz w:val=\"28\"/><w:szCs w:val=\"28\"/></w:rPr>"
+ "</w:style>";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();       
        
  XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();
  CTNumbering cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(cTAbstractNumDecimalXML);
  CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = cTNumbering.getAbstractNumArray(0);
  XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
 
  BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
  BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);

  XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();
  CTStyles cTStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(cTStyleNormal);
  CTStyle cTStyle = cTStyles.getStyleArray(0);
  styles.addStyle(new XWPFStyle(cTStyle));
  cTStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(cTStyleH1XML);
  cTStyle = cTStyles.getStyleArray(0);
  styles.addStyle(new XWPFStyle(cTStyle));
  cTStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(cTStyleH2XML);
  cTStyle = cTStyles.getStyleArray(0);
  styles.addStyle(new XWPFStyle(cTStyle));
  cTStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(cTStyleH3XML);
  cTStyle = cTStyles.getStyleArray(0);
  styles.addStyle(new XWPFStyle(cTStyle));

  cTStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(cTStyleTOC1);
  cTStyle = cTStyles.getStyleArray(0);
  styles.addStyle(new XWPFStyle(cTStyle));
  cTStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(cTStyleTOC2);
  cTStyle = cTStyles.getStyleArray(0);
  styles.addStyle(new XWPFStyle(cTStyle));

  createParagraphs(document, numID, 
   new String[] {"First Level",
                 "Second Level",
                 "First Level",
                 "Second Level",
                 "Third Level",
                 "Second Level",
                 "Third Level",
                 "Second Level",
                 "First Level"}
  );

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Table of contents:");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  CTSimpleField toc = paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
  toc.setInstr("TOC \\* MERGEFORMAT");
  toc.setDirty(true);
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\CreateWordNumberedHeadings.docx");   
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }

 public static void createParagraphs(XWPFDocument doc, BigInteger numID, String[] content) {
  for (String value : content) {
   XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
   para.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
   para.setNumID(numID);
   para.setStyle("Heading1");
   if (value.contains("Second")) {
    para.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().addNewIlvl().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    para.setStyle("Heading2");
   }
   if(value.contains("Third")) {
    para.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().addNewIlvl().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
    para.setStyle("Heading3");
   }
   XWPFRun run = para.createRun();
   run.setText(value);
   para = doc.createParagraph();
   run = para.createRun();
   run.setText("Lorem ipsum semit dolor ...");
   run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  } 
 }
}
```

Edit: Adding pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-full -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: See my supplements to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335464/how-to-set-table-of-contents-font-style-including-font-color-font-size-and-bol/43447843#43447843. In short: Do'nt use `STOnOff` anymore. Instead do using `boolean` values.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter, It's still not working for me. Is there any way, you can share your pom.xml or can you please check mine. or work with my pom.xml. 

Also, can java 8 version can cause the issue?

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you for boolean value suggestion, Now, not getting the error. but as I have updated the code file with boolean value as well as with pom.xml. I am using java 8. Still not able to create table. Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Don't mix POI versions. See https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204. Why the mix of versions 5.1.0 and 5.0.0 in your pom.xml?

Comment: @AxelRichter I have updated the code  little bit as well as pom.xml. But still no luck, I am not sure what's wrong here. I am not getting table of content. Can you please check it?  Is it java version which causes the issue?

Comment: Works for me using exactly your code as well as for your previous question. Not clear what your misconfiguration might be.

Comment: Completely unaware of the issue then. I will be very glad if you guide me/help me for this or share your configuration for this. I am adding my project here for your reference, so you can check it. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KYO3uZpTEtaHFbOyMemeEGv4_g17gZoG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AxelRichter It works for me on my personal laptop, but not working on my office machine, and same issue in production as well. So I am mostly good from my side. Thank you for your help.