# org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: union value 'false' does not match any members of 'ST_OnOff in namespace

Tags: java, apache-poi, tableofcontents

Hi I am tring to create table of contents in word document using java apachi poi library. The I found a code form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335464/how-to-set-table-of-contents-font-style-including-font-color-font-size-and-bol#:%7E:text=even%20cannot%20get,using%20XML%20like%3A). But when I run the code it gives me below error

> rg.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: union value 'false' does not match any members of 'ST_OnOff in namespace http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/sharedTypes

the code which creating the error is

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
CTP ctP = paragraph.getCTP();
CTSimpleField toc = ctP.addNewFldSimple();
toc.setInstr("TOC \\* MERGEFORMAT");
toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);
```

Poi version 5.2.3

Comment: You have not fully read my anser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335464/how-to-set-table-of-contents-font-style-including-font-color-font-size-and-bol#:%7E:text=even%20cannot%20get,using%20XML%20like%3A: "To make this code work using apache poi versions greater than 4...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Microsoft Word field shall be set "dirty", to tell Microsoft Word to refresh that field while next time opening the file, then this has been done using set `CTSimpleField` property `dirty` to `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff.TRUE` up to Apache POI version 4.x.x.

From version 5.0.0 on the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff` is not more present. There are other `STOnOff` classes but none of them provide `TRUE`/`FALSE` but only `ON`/`OFF`. But now `CTSimpleField.setDirty` accepts boolean values directly.

To make this code work using Apache POI versions greater than 4, you need changing the following:

```
...
//import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;
...
  //toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);
  toc.setDirty(true);
...
```